# OAuth HwioBundle, different socialNetWork

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

I work to project in Symfony which have registration HWIOBundle for different social network. If user enters for example LinkedIn and some time for GitHub I has two user in database. Who knows how to do was one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user's email is similar in both social accounts, you can use email field to identify user. You should create user provider class. If user with provided social token won't be found in database, user provider will try to find user by email and add new social token for specified social network to existing user entity.

Code example.

services.xml

```
<service id="app.my_user_provider" class="AppBundle\Security\FOSUBUserProvider">
    <argument type="service" id="user_manager"/>
    <argument type="collection">
      <argument key="facebook">%facebook_id%</argument>
      <argument key="google">%google_id%</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher"/>
</service>
```

security.yml, [firewall section](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-configuring_the_security_layer.md)

```
    oauth:
        resource_owners:
            facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
            google: "/login/check-google"
        login_path: /login
        failure_path: /login

        oauth_user_provider:
            service: app.my_user_provider
```

src/AppBundle/Security/FOSUBUserProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();

        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($service);
        $setterId = $setter . 'Id';
        $setterToken = $setter . 'AccessToken';

        //disconnect previously connected user
        if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username))) {
            $previousUser->$setterId(null);
            $previousUser->$setterToken(null);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
        }

        //connect current user
        $user->$setterId($username);
        $user->$setterToken($response->getAccessToken());

        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        $email = $response->getEmail();

        $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));
        if (null === $user) {
            $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($email);

            $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
            $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($service);
            $setterId = $setter . 'Id';
            $setterToken = $setter . 'AccessToken';

            if (null === $user) {
                $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
                $user->$setterId($username);
                $user->$setterToken($response->getAccessToken());

                $user->setUsername($username);
                $user->setEmail($email);
                $user->setPassword($username);
                $user->setEnabled(true);
                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

                return $user;
            } else {
                $user->$setterId($username);
                $user->$setterToken($response->getAccessToken());

                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

                return $user;
            }
        }

        //if user exists - go with the HWIOAuth way
        $user = parent::loadUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);

        $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';

        //update access token
        $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if in other socialnetwork come additional information, example entry for github and I have fielв skype, but github not have skype. Vk have skype and when I entry for vk I wantset new information. I add:
`
else {
$user->$setterId($username);
$user->$setterToken($response->getAccessToken());
$serviceProvider = $service."Provider";
$user = $this->$serviceProvider->setUserData($user, $response);
$this->userManager->updateUser($user);
return $user;`
in else and then code work right